# django-nonrel exclude listfield from admin

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, django-nonrel

I've ran into a typical problem where I have a ListField in a model.

I'd like to use the Django admin to play around with the object and the ListField isn't that crucial, it's a list of embedded objects that I can live without.

When I use this, I get the error on the main admin page. If I don't use the ModelAdmin object when registering the original Item object, I only get the error if I try to add an Item.

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('bids',)

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

How to properly exclude the "bids" ListField then?

Answer (score 3):

I worked round it by making my ListField non editable, as I couldnt get `exclude` to work for me either..

eg:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bids = ListField(EmbeddedModelField('Bid'), editable=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `ListField` and override `formfield` so that it returns `None`.

Returning `None` from `formfield(...)` means that the field should be excluded from all forms, so you need remove the `exclude = ['bids']` thing from your `ModelAdmin`.

Alternatively, you can make `formfield(...)` return a proper `forms.Field` subclass -- to display e.g. a text version, use something like

```
class Item(models.Model):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return super(Item, self).formfield(form_class=YourCustomFormField, **kwargs)
```

To exclude it from the admin, you can still use `exclude`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.Field.formfield

Put your field subclass into `yourapp/fields.py`.

Comment: Jonas, thanks for your answer mate. I'm still very new to Django and Python. Where should I define this Subclass of ListField? I'm thinking within my models.py in my own app, so as to keep it independent.
Also when you say, return none from formfield() do you mean it should implement a formfield() method that just returns none? How would I go about for example, returning a text version of my embedded object?
Thanks bro

Comment: Yeah really return `None`. I added some additional info to my answer.

Comment: Jonas thanks once again! I'm getting confused here, between the Model definition, the Field definition and the FormField. So what I'm trying to do here, is SubClass ListField so that I can print (and ideally save) instances of the EmbeddedObjectField it contains.